# Load webview in the top of the page

Tags: android, webview

I'm working in a WebView App.
In my last change, i added a function to hide the app bar when i scroll down in webview. Nice !!!
But i have noticed a problem. I will try explain.
Let's suposse that i'm in a News Site, and i'm openning the last news. The most recent news are in the start of the page, and the last news are close to the ends of the page, so i open the last news, and my webview load the url. When the url is loaded, my webview is in the end of the site, and not in the start. It started after i added my "webview" inside of "NestedScrollView". Looks like NestedScrollView is saving my position, and it's affecting my position in the web page. How to fix this ?

Edit: My webview is load inside Framelayout, my webview is a fragment.

WebView Layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipelayout">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/inicio_pagina"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></WebView>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

FrameLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

App_Bar_Main

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main"
    android:id="@+id/include" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/face"
    android:scaleType="center"/>
```

Edit 2: WebView Fragment

```
public class InicioPagina extends Fragment {

private ProgressBar prg;

SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;

NestedScrollView NestedScrollView;

public WebView myWebView;

public static InicioPagina newInstance() {
    InicioPagina fragment = new InicioPagina();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.iniciopagina, container, false);
    prg = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    NestedScrollView = (NestedScrollView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nested_scroll_view);
    mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipelayout);
    myWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.inicio_pagina);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com.br/");

    //*Ativar JavaScript
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    //*Forçar links para abrir no WebView ao invés do navegador
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    NestedScrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);


    myWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            myWebView.reload();
            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });

    myWebView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                WebView webView = (WebView) v;

                switch(keyCode)
                {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        if(webView.canGoBack())
                        {
                            webView.goBack();
                            return true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

public class WebViewClient extends android.webkit.WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        prg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        prg.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Make `id` for the `NestedScrollView`

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical">
```

2) Create `NestedScrollView` object 
3) When the new URL is loaded, set the scroll property of the 
 `nestedScrollView`object to 0,0.

```
nestedScrollViewObj.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Comment: Don't work. I don't know if i did it right, so i updated the post with the WebView Fragment, take a look please

Comment: make sure the page is complete loaded first.